# It is possible to run cmd commands from swf?

Tags: cmd, flash, external

I have got Vectorian `Giotto` and `FlashDevelop` and I have an idea of creating an interactive wallpaper (ex., desktop without icons, you click on the barrel and context menu appears, click on spaceship and "my computer" folder opens).

I found out that it is possible to make a wallpaper for windows in `swf` converted to `html`.

However, I have no idea how to run some cmd commands ( after for example clicking spaceship  :: runs `cd "D:\Doc\intro.exe"` ) as events in `swf` button.

I'm new in `flash`, but I know `Java,C#,C++` ...

Sorry for my english